# Two XLM accounts via Ledger

Tags: ledger-nano

The Ledger "Stellar account viewer" (https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003797194) apparently one hooks up to just one Ledger account. But I want to have **two** XLM accounts via Ledger. Can I do that, and if so how?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question for Ledger's support, not this forum.

Comment: I did contact Ledger support, and they told me to ask the Stellar community!

Answer (score 1):

Simply uncheck `Use default account` and use a different derivation path on login. 44' stands for bip44 standard, 148' stands for stellar and the third number is the account number (0' is the default account). So simply use 44'/148'/1' for your second, 44'/148'/2' third ... account.

[image]

@see [SEP-5 stellar hd key derivation](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/blob/master/ecosystem/sep-0005.md)

Comment: Be careful with that though, I'm not sure wallets support anything other than the default account.